# Closed+hot index or warm+hot index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm administrating an elastic stack at the moment and my current method right now is closing indexes older than 2 weeks and keeping the last 2 weeks in hot state. If people need to check logs older than 2 weeks they contact me and I just reopen them until they're finished. There is a considerable amount of daha flow to the stack and if I don't do reguler cleaning/closing I mostly get request timeouts from kibana. Is it better to change the older logs' states to warm/cold rather than closing? Will I notice a performance boost while querying?

Answer (score 0):

Hot / warm / cold is to create different tiers of hardware (generally higher storage density in relation to memory as data gets older). This will not improve your performance without additional hardware.

Instead of closing the indices, you could look into [frozen indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/frozen-indices.html). They are like a middle ground between open and closed index with a limited set of resources (they have their own throttled threadpool).